# How can I read a large XML file efficiently with a low memory footprint

Tags: c#, xml, algorithm, optimization

I need to read a large XML file in c# but with a few other considerations.

- XML File is roughly 70,000 KB in size.
- Each entry is timestamped, I only want entries that are less than 1 hour old.
- The data is ordered. Oldest to newest. (I cannot change the order from newest to oldest because this is not my XML file)
- Shouldn't use a large memory footprint.

Formatting is as such:

```
<RecordSet>
  <Record>
    <TimeStamp>...</TimeStamp>
    ...
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <TimeStamp>...</TimeStamp>
    ...
  </Record>
</RecordSet>
```

There are a few obvious routes that I've considered such as using XmlReader and going linearly, even using concurrency. However, due to the nature of the data (ordered, only need a subset etc) I am sure there is a more efficient way to retrieve this. I have also tried methods of traversing the XML backwards but it's unclear if this is possible without loading the data upfront.

While sample code would be nice, any theoretical approaches would be greatly appreciated too.

Comment: Have a look at this project.  https://github.com/xmlexplorer/windows   Also see this Q&As https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308679/lightweight-xml-viewer-that-can-handle-large-files

Comment: "I am sure there is a more efficient way to retrieve this." Do you really *need* it to be more time-efficient than the obvious solution with XmlReader, which would be sufficiently memory-efficient? What are your precise performance constraints?

Comment: You can use (1) LINQ to XML .Net  Framework API, it supports GB size XML files, or (2) XSLT 3.0 that supports streaming.

Comment: `XmlReader` is fully streaming, so memory footprint will be fairly low at any given time. 70Mb is not *that* large though.

Comment: Parse the file line by line manually to get the latest prints. Then you can pass the result into xml objects or keep parsing manually. Not a rocket science if you have simple xml. Takes little memory and cpu. Can be done in 30min. 5 times less than reading blogs and learning linq to xml

Comment: FYI. XML is never going to be an optimal solution for memory efficiency. There is no memory bound, forward only, general purpose parser for XML. If you must use XML, you will likely need to write your own state machine to use `XmlReader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fast xml-parser reading the data (file) might be the bottleneck.
If this is the case you can try to **avoid reading the whole file to speed things up** (in this special case: ordered data, simple xml-structure).

You can implement a kind of binary search for the point where the date begins you are interested in. And only read and parse the file from this position onwards.

This is only possible if your data is read from a device whit random access (which is true for most media now a days except if you read from some kind of stream).

Use binary search to decide a byte-position to start reading than you need to skip read bytes until you detect a new `<Record>` to start and than decide if you need to jump (based on the timestamp) forward or backward in your data to find the one-hour-ago-position.

Space-related you never need more than the size of one record as buffer while reading the data plus space to store the result.

---

To clear up the discussion with  @jdweng below:

- If reading the whole file is fast enough for you use jdweng's answer.
- If you are willing to write a bit of code yourself (to detect where the next `Record`-Tag starts (which is easy for this special xml-structure)) **you can avoid reading the whole file**. and just use e.g. XmlfReader after you found the tag you want to start to extract the data.

Comment: This is XML data.  Do you expect OP to create his own XML parser when there is already a great  XML Reader that will do the job?

Comment: -1 A binary search would presuppose the existence of an index of tokens in the XML. The creation of which is hardly going to be "speedy". Additionally, XML is not an appendable data structure, so I'd like to know how you suppose you keep an index upto data.

Comment: @jdweng: If you want to avoid reading the whole file you need to write at least a parser that can detect the begin of '<Record>` after you detected the byte-position of it you can use any xml-parser you want to parse further on.

Comment: @Aron: You do not need an index (you binary search on the bytes of the file), the timestamps within the `Record` should be sufficient to detect on which side of the desired time-stamp the current read record is.

Comment: That is exactly what the Xml Reader does.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @MrSmith42 How do you jump to the point in the file that a timestamp exists? How do you know how deeply nested in the XML you are at each record without having walked the whole graph upto that point?

Comment: @Aron; I jump in the file to a byte position dictated by binary search over all bytes. Most likely at the position we are not at a timestamp but somewhere within any possible tag.Than read byte by byte forward until you detect the start of the next `Record` than decide based on its timestamp at which byte-position to jump next,

Comment: @jdweng: I'm sure `Xml Reader` does not start parsing somewhere within the file but parsing the file from the start. My attempt is not to read the whole file but probe it at different positions (via binary search) and start parsing from the desired record onwards. This is possible in this special case because of the 'simple' xml-structure of the file.

Comment: When you parse  xml you have to match start and end tags.  Reading in chunks will be complicated because you have to match start and end tags.  Xml is not simple nor Regular!  Again.  Why create a method where a library already exists.

Comment: @jdweng: In this special case (this specific xml structure in the question) you can find the `Record`-tags quite easily. The goal of my attempt is to **read less than the hole file**. That is what a usual xml-parser would need to to to handle general xml. if reading & parsing the whole file is fast enough for you, ignore my answer.

Comment: Xmlreader does not read the entire file into memory at one time.

Comment: @jdweng: I never implied that but it most likely reads the entire file. (that what my attempt avoids)

Comment: XmlfReader does not read the entire file.  For huge XML files (larger than 1GB), XmlReader always works. Other libraries fail and give Out of Memory.

Comment: Yes you have to read the entire stream.  But the entire stream is not in memory at one time.  Only the current buffer is in memory.  See source : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReader.cs,4d066fd05db57366

Comment: @jdweng: That's all my answer is about how to avoid reading the whole file if you are only interested in  the tail (which you can find without reading everything from the start) [p.s I never said that the entire file would be in RAM at any time while  XmlfReader parses it]

Comment: My point is you do not have to write the code because the library already exists.  My first comment was "This is XML data. Do you expect OP to create his own XML parser when there is already a great XML Reader that will do the job? "

Comment: @jdweng: My point is you can avoid reading the whole file without much effort (and still using any xml-parser to parse only the part you are interested in)

Answer (score 1):

For huge xml file XmlReader is the only method that works.  I like using a Powershell script with Xml Linq.  Your xml is not valid.  The timestamp open and closing tags do not match.  One has a uppercase S and the other lowercase S.

```
using assembly System.Xml
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$FILENAME = "c:\temp\test.xml"

$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($FILENAME)
while($reader.EOF -eq $False)
{
   if ($reader.Name -ne "Record")
   {
     $reader.ReadToFollowing("Record") | out-null
   }
   if ($reader.EOF -eq $False)
   {
       $record = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::ReadFrom($reader)
       $timestamp = $record.Element("Timestamp").Value 
       Write-Output "Timestamp = $timestamp"
   }
}
```